# How to change style of multiple elements with a single script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I want to make a dark mode switcher for my website. I have a small script for start. It basically toggle the CSS style. But if I leave or refresh the page the style won't stay obviously...

```
<style>
    .mystyle {
        color:red !important;
        background-color: black !important;
    }

</style>
```

```
<script>
    function init(){ 
    var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
</script>
```

So my goal is to make this toggle button stay on its current state throughout the whole site even after refresh or change page...

Comment: You would need to store the state somewhere. You could use cookies or use local storage for it. When you load the page, you check the saved state (by reading the cookie value or local storage value) and based on it's value toggle the class.

Comment: Here is a method using cookies. https://jsfiddle.net/0f6d3w91/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach would be to save the state in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), and when loading the page toggle the class according to its value.

Here is how you could implement it:

```html
<style>
  .dark-mode {
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <button onclick="toggleMode()">Switch Mode</button>
</body>

<script>
  const body = document.body;

  if (localStorage.mode === 'dark') {
    body.classList.add("dark-mode")
  };

  function toggleMode() {
    body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    localStorage.setItem(
      'mode', localStorage.mode === 'light' || localStorage.mode === undefined ? 'dark' : 'light'
    );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello! Im new to scripting... Couldn't made it work. Can you make a jsfiddle sample?

Comment: @mojito000, I added a sample to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try removing and adding classes using add() and remove() functions, the following code may work:

```
<script>
  var onOff=false; //to check of the class is active or not
  function init(){ 
  var element = document.body;
  if(onOff === false){
   element.classList.add("mystyle");
   onOff = true;
  }eles{
      element.classList.remove("mystyle");
      onOff = false;
  }
}
</script>
```